# Regular expression to return word present in the 1st enclosed parentheses

Tags: java, regex

Example:

1. `((UINT32)((384UL*1024UL) - 1UL))` should return "UINT32"
2. `(char)abc`  should return "char".
3. `((int)xyz)`  should return "int".

Answer (score 4):

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\(([^()]*)\\)");
    String[] tests = {
            "((UINT32)((384UL*1024UL) - 1UL))",
            "(char)abc",
            "((int)xyz)"
    };

    for (String s : tests) {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        if (m.find())
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```

Prints

```
UINT32
char
int
```

Explanation of the regular expression:

- `\\(` Start with a `(`
- `(` start capturing group
- `[^()]*` anything but `(` and `)` 0 or more times
- `)` end capturing group
- `\\)` end with a `)`.

---

Using regular expressions is a bit of an overkill though. You could also do

```
int close = s.indexOf(')');
int open = s.lastIndexOf('(', close);
result = s.substring(open+1, close);
```

Comment: It is for me... For me the code snippet prints the three lines below. Thus, the second test `(char)abc` results in `char`, which is the expected result, no? See http://ideone.com/pEoyg

Comment: case 1: (int)10
case 2: (int)(10)
case 3: (long)(100000)(10)

Comment: @aioobe: Why not put the closing paren in the character class as well?  Then you wouldn't need the reluctant quantifier: `[^()]*`

Comment: I had that at first, but with escapes on the `)` it was one more character :-) But from your comment I recall that escapes is not needed in character-classes, so I'll update :-)

Comment: Thanks For your great support.Its working fine.There was fault in my program itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\(([^\\(\\)]+?)\\)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
if (m.find())
  result = m.group(1);
```

Comment: you may want to have `*` instead of `+?` in order to be able to handle a first enclosed parenthesis that is empty.